# Between Operator for varchar datatype

Tags: mysqli

I have column 'hdd' having values '1GB','500GB,''1TB' and '100TB'

When retrieving rows where value between 1TB  and 100 TB like this:

```
select * from product where hdd between '1TB' and '100TB'
```

It returns the rows that contain 1GB also.

Also tried like this:

```
select *
from product
where cast(replace(hdd, 'TB','') as int) between 1 and 100
```

It said error near ')int

I'm using mysqli.

Comment: I'm using mysqli

Answer (score 3):

The column that you have is a VARCHAR so the ordering applied by the RDBMS will be alphabetical instead of numeric.

What is the smallest possible unit of storage for a HDD these days? GB? One way to solve your problem would be to create another column that transforms the storage into GB (or some other unit). Make sure that this column is integer or numeric and not a VARCHAR. Using your example data and assuming 1000 GB per TB:

```
'1GB', 1
'500GB', 500
'1TB', 1000
'100TB', 100000
```

Filtering on the second column is a much more straightforward way to get the results that you want.

If you don't want to create a new column, it would be possible, but messy, to do that conversion within the SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

1GB, 100TB, etc are just strings of text with no arithmetic meaning regarding which is greater.  I'm assuming your column only has ONE value, like 1GB or 500GB, and not all of those values

I think you'd have to attempt something like using REPLACE(hdd,'GB',000000) or REPLACE(hdd,'TB',000000000) and using numeric comparisons in your between.

It's definitely not going to perform optimally.